# USER IN ORACLE 19

Tags: oracle, roles, oracle19c

I have a doubt, why I can't connect to my new created user

I create my new user with this command (logged in with system account and my pdb)

```
CREATE USER teste
identified by teste
default tablespace users
temporary tablespace temp;
```

and I give this grant

```
GRANT 
create procedure,
create session,
create sequence,
create synonym,
create table,
create any type,
create trigger,
create any index,
create view
to role_programador;
```

After, I give this ROLE for my new account

```
GRANT role_programador to teste;
```

and when I'm trying to connect to this account `teste` with my password `teste` in CMD, I receive this error and I don't know why! Anyone could help me?

```
Microsoft Windows [versão 10.0.19042.867]
(c) 2020 Microsoft Corporation. Todos os direitos reservados.

C:\Users\Gustavo>SET oracle_sid=orcl

C:\Users\Gustavo>sqlplus teste/teste

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Qui Abr 8 07:34:21 2021
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-01017: password/name invalid; log-on negado


Informe o nome do usuario: teste
Informe a senha:
ERROR:
```

Comment: You can't use SID to connect to a PDB. You must use SERVICE_NAME. Also, you have not set the role to actually be active for your user, so it will not have any default privileges (like CREATE SESSION). Make sure it is set to default: `alter user teste default role role_programador;`

Comment: I put this command with my SQLDEVELOPER

"alter user teste default role role_programador;"

received this:
"User TESTE changed." 

I don't know if I'm right, but my SERVICE_NAME is orcl


ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )

C:\Users\Gustavo>sqlplus teste@orcl/teste

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Qui Abr 8 08:09:42 2021
Version 19.3.0.0.0

ERROR:
ORA-12154


I don't have idea what I'm doing wrong

Comment: What is your PDB name?. try this `sqlplus teste/teste@localhost:1521/pdbname` or create service entry in tnsnames.ora file for your pdb